# Facebook SDK: How to correct initialize FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy with old token?

Tags: oauth, access-token, facebook-ios-sdk

How to correct initialize `FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy`?

I have: `facebook-ios-sdk` (not new, but 3.0).

Also, i have an iOS-project, thtat must run under iOS 5.*

And i have a trouble:

How to correct initialize session, if it must be reopen (not open)?

I have a **token** from last session and i want to login with this token.

But for this i need to create a `FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy` instance.

How to do this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why do you need to use FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy? Why not using the normal login workflow?

Comment: @ale0xB application, that i develop, takes a token from server (not facebook) if it was exists. and if not, it (application) login on facebook. so, if i can create `CachingStrategy`, i can open session without login. Maybe i wrong, fix me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said before, i need this to create session and open it.

Let's see, what i want:

1. load **TOKEN** from my server. (and misc info about user).
2. create session
3. open session

NOTE:

It can be, that FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy instance was not saved on device.

And i need to create it.

And this is my algorithm: (code will be posted later)

1. load **TOKEN**, **expirationDate**, **userID** from my server.
2. create FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy instance manually, input in it's settings dictionary all fields, loaded in first step and(!) PERMISSIONS (it predefined in my app).
3. init session.
4. open session.

Success!